# Kentico: new form field does not display on live site

Tags: forms, kentico

[Kentico v8.2.4]

I have an existing contact form (built by someone else) and I'm trying to add a new form field to it.

I've successfully added the field in the back-end within the form builder, and **I've checked "show on public form"** check-box within the field settings. However, the new form field is not showing up on the live site.

In fact, I can successfully edit any of the existing form fields and the changes take effect on the live site immediately, but when I try to add a new form field (no matter the type), it doesn't show up on the live website.

Any ideas what I need to do to make my new form field show up ?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. It looks like I needed to alter the "Layout" area, and add:

$$input:StateProvince$$

To the list of items in the layout. That solved it.

Comment: That's right. If the Form > Layout > General > Layout Type was set to "Use automatically generated form layout" then it would have automatically added the field. In your case I assume it was set to "Use custom form layout" and HTML. In which case you need to manually add new fields to the Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the field in any custom form layout you have set up.

Also check if you are using an Alternate Form Layout.